# how do i unwrap multiple objects to secondary uv map?

Tags: uv, lighting, unity

let me preface this by saying my knowledge of blender and unity is limited.

i have here a mesh exported by a program that exports minecraft worlds (mineways) and im trying to bake lighting onto it in unity, however wherever there's a border in UV's i get nasty lighting, (that's using unity's auto generate lightmap uv's) all i need is a secondary UV map, which unity will use by default to bake lighting onto, what im trying to do is to select all of my blocks (all of which are separate meshes, and have separate materials) unwrap them all into a **secondary** UVmap, (to preserve the primary one for textures) and then save the .blend file which unity supports[image: mesh shown here]

Comment: Hi :). In the right *UV Maps* panel click the plus button. Boom, you have a second uv map. Now select it (click on it) an unwrap :)

Comment: @JachymMichal if i do that, it only adds a second UV to the first object i have selected, and once i unwrap to that UV it also unwraps over the primary UV of every other object, which i need for textures, so this doesn't work